# How do you use an async function as the callback in setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord.js

I have three functions: `setAccurateTimeout`, `unmuteUser`, and a `setTimeout` that is meant to call unmuteUser after a given duration. (For the purposes of demonstration I have hard-coded the duration).

I'm trying to understand what exactly is happening here as upon code execution, it looks like `setTimeout` is being executed immediately instead of waiting for the duration to lapse.

I imagine that I just am not grasping what exactly the interaction is between setTimeout and an async function and if someone could explain that, I'd probably understand what to do here.

setAccurateTimeout

```
export function setAccurateTimeout (delay: string, callbackRef: Promise<void>) {
    const delayMs = durationToMilliseconds(delay)
    if(delayMs) {
        return setTimeout(() => {
            callbackRef
        }, 120000)
    }
}
```

unmuteUser

```
public async unmuteUser (user: GuildMember, role: Role) {
    user.roles.remove(role)
    // does other irrelevant stuff after this
}
```

calling setAccurateTimeout

```
public async muteUser (user: GuildMember, reason: string, duration: string | null): Promise<GuildMember> {
    ...
    if (duration) {
        const timerID = setAccurateTimeout(duration, this.unmuteUser(mutedUser, muteRole))
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: "[what is] the interaction between setTimeout and an async function?". I would say that setTimeout is an async function. You can use a sync function as the argument to setTimeout and it will run after code which comes after the setTimeout function.

Comment: Could you make this code a self-contained [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE, with no undeclared/undefined types/values or pseudocode?  I assume the problem you're having is that you are *calling* `this.unmuteUser()` inside `muteUser()`, instead of passing a callback that calls it or creating a `Promise` that only calls it when resolved.  I'd write up a fixed version, but I can't easily test it without a [mre], and so I'm less inclined to try.  If you do [edit] to do this and want me to take another look, please mention @jcalz in a comment afterwards to notify me. Good luck!

Comment: Why not put the code in a snippet in your question?

Comment: you know what @jcalz that's actually a very good point - I realize that by passing the parameters themselves that I'm actually calling the function instead of passing a reference to it. I'm going to work on refactoring that and then if I have another issue I will just update the current post.